# Select columns based on sum

Tags: r

I have a data frame with many columns of genes and rows, for example

```
id  treatment time gene1 gene2 gene3 …
1      A       1     2     0    2    …
2      A       2     0     0    3    …
3      A       3     0     0    4    …
4      B       4     0     0    0    …
5      B       5     0     0    2    …
6      B       3     1     0    1    …
7      C       5     0     0    2    …
```

I would like to keep the all the first several columns (in the example data is three, but there are many columns in real data) and the genes columns that the column sum is > 0.

I would appreciate any help on my question. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure on whether you want to retain rows or columns with the sum of entries > 0.

In case of the former, you can use `rowSums` like this

```
df[rowSums(df[, grep("gene", names(df))]) > 0, ]
#id treatment time gene1 gene2 gene3
#1  1         A    1     2     0     2
#2  2         A    2     0     0     3
#3  3         A    3     0     0     4
#5  5         B    5     0     0     2
#6  6         B    3     1     0     1
#7  7         C    5     0     0     2
```

Or to retain only those columns with the sum of entries > 0 you can use `colSums`

```
df[, names(df) %in% c(
    names(df)[grep("gene", names(df), invert = T)],
    names(which(colSums(df[, grep("gene", names(df))]) > 0)))]
#  id treatment time gene1 gene3
#1  1         A    1     2     2
#2  2         A    2     0     3
#3  3         A    3     0     4
#4  4         B    4     0     0
#5  5         B    5     0     2
#6  6         B    3     1     1
#7  7         C    5     0     2
```

This assumes that all gene columns contain the word `"gene"` (and all non-gene columns do *not* contain the word `"gene"`).

Or more concise (thanks @Shree),

```
df[, c(rep(T, 3), colSums(df[, -c(1:3)]) > 0)]
```

which assumes that the first 3 columns are non-gene columns (and the remaining columns are all gene columns).

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "id  treatment   time    gene1   gene2   gene3
1   A   1   2   0   2
2   A   2   0   0   3
3   A   3   0   0   4
4   B   4   0   0   0
5   B   5   0   0   2
6   B   3   1   0   1
7   C   5   0   0   2", header = T)
```

Comment: I think OP wants to remove columns. Probably needs `colSums` with column subseting.

Comment: @Shree Ah yes, you might be right. I've made an edit.

Comment: I'd suggest `df[, c(rep(T, 3), colSums(df[, -c(1:3)]) > 0)]` for being concise. It's not generic like yours though.

Comment: @Shree Yes, that's much more concise. Thanks:-) Your solution assumes that the first 3 columns are the non-gene columns, whereas my solution is based on column names. I've made an edit to show both options.

Comment: @Maurits, thank you very much. May I ask what the meaning with code "rep(T, 3)", especially the "T"?

Comment: @Bio_former `rep(T, 3)` is short for `rep(TRUE, 3)` which generates a vector `c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)`. This ensures that we select the first three (non-gene) columns.

Comment: @Bio_farmer You're very welcome. If this answers your question, please consider closing the question by setting the green checkmark next to the answer. That way you help keeping SO tidy and make it easier for other SO users to identify relevant questions.